# Difference between <beans:beans> and <beans>

Tags: xml, spring

I just bean through two web application and in both project's "applicationContext.xml" file there is a tag

```
<beans:beans>
 ... 
</beans:beans>
```

and in another is

```
<beans> 
... 
</beans>
```

Can someone explain to me is there any difference?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no semantic difference, they mean exactly the same thing. It's just a difference in how their XML namespaces are declared.

You'll see that the first example declares the namespace like this, which declares a namespace prefix `beans:` and binds it to the namespace URI `http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans`:

```
<beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" ...
```

The second will use the "default" namespace, which binds the same URI to the default namespace (i.e. the one with no prefix):

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" ...
```

For more details, go and read up on XML Namespaces.

Answer (score 3):

`<beans:beans>` refers to `beans` tag from `beans` namespace. `<beans>` refer to `beans` tag of the default namespace. If the default namespace is `beans` then there is no difference.